# Intuition behind quadratic form of SPD matrices $S\Sigma S$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition, positive-definite

Is there an intuition behind the quadratic form of SPD (symmetric and positive definite) matrices:

$$(S, \Sigma) \in \mathcal{S}_{++}\times\mathcal{S}_{++}  \mapsto S\Sigma S$$ where $S$ and $\Sigma$ are positive definite symmetric $d\times d$ matrices.

I thought it measures the similarty of the rows/ columns of $S$ transformed by the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$ since the $i,j-th$ entry of $S\Sigma S$ is $s_i^T \Sigma s_j$ where $s_i$ is the i-th column of S and using eigendecomposition $\Sigma=U^TDU$ one gets
$s_i^T \Sigma s_j= (Us_i)^TD (Us_j)$.

Is there any other interpretation / intution behind the quadratic form of SPD matrices?